# Projector for high room

Tags: projector

I am looking for a projector mounted on the ceiling for home use (watching movies).

I've read that the projector should be mounted at the same height as the upper edge of the projection screen.

[image: Mounting]

We have a quite high living room of 2.90 m, so for a screen suspended 90 cm from the ground and 100 cm high, the projector would have to be on a holder 90-100 cm long (and preferably adjustable in height if we wanted to place the screen slightly higher). We don't like the idea of a meter-long handle sticking out of the ceiling.

Is there any alternative to this solution? I have seen ideas that the projector throws the image at an angle, but then the image will have a trapezoidal shape and the solution is a tilt-shift lens or keystone correction.

[image: Angle]

What projector do you recommend in such a situation?

Answer (score 1):

`I've read that the projector should be mounted at the same height as the upper edge of the projection screen.`

This is not true, most modern, respectable projectors will allow you to adjust for angular projection.  I am using this one, for example and I am happy with it.

You can mount your projector where you want, vertically.  IN my case, the pantry is behind that wall and has a lower ceiling.  So, it actually sits on the ceiling, with a hole through the wall into the media room.

[Epson EH-LS650B](https://www.epson.co.nz/products/projector/EH-LS650B.asp?groupid=127)

[image]